# Magento2 Home page cms: from where content is coming in my home page cms

Tags: magento2

I am seeing that couple of blocks getting called in my home page because i am seeing them rendered in fontend but they are not being called from cms page content. Is there any other place i can look for?

Answer (score 0):

It can be called from various places as below:

1. You can see what template files being called in Homepage CMS page, than can search the block id in those template files.
2. Search in theme directory.
3. possible if there is layout handle hook in any extension (but for that you have to check in all custom modules)

**The best way** to detect is to **turn on Template path hints** if it is coming from phtml(template) file than you will definitely get the location.